# Please re-open and migrate to Super User

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question, migration

This question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16879159/excel-2007-stacked-column-chart-display-subvalues is perfectly suited for SuperUser. I flagged it to be migrated to SU but now I find it has been closed instead as "too localized".

Why?

Never mind the "pregnancy" related data sample. The question is about splitting a column in a stacked column chart to display its sub-groups. Why is that too localised? It is not. It just off-topic for SO and better suited at SU.

Closing the question as too localized does not help the OP and it does not do much to invite more expert opinions on how to solve a very valid question about charting techniques in Excel.

Please re-open the question and migrate it to SU, which will greatly help the OP and others.

Comment: Did you flag it for a moderator asking that they migrate it to SuperUser?  Even though it is closed you can still flag it.

Comment: It should not be reopened, as it's not on-topic for SO. The standard procedure is close, then (possibly) migrate. A question does not have to be reopened to be migrated by a moderator.

Comment: OK, I may not be up to par with the procedure and steps involved. So maybe it does not need re-opening to be migrated. And @bluefeet, I clicked the "flag" link and flagged it to be off-topic and recommended moving to SU. Is that what you refer to as "flag it to a moderator"? If so, then yes, I did that.

Comment: Since the question was closed, then you can flag it as other and ask that this be migrated to SuperUser.

Comment: @bluefeet, I don't seem to make myself clear, so again: I HAVE flagged it as **off topic** and I HAVE asked for it to be migrated to SU. I used the standard choices in the user interface. What more can I do? Now I now find it is closed, instead of moved. What am I expected to do now? Stomp my foot?

Comment: @teylyn: Flag for a moderator, select the "other" option and explain the situation.

Comment: OK. I understand now. Done another flag.

Comment: The close reason reads "closed as off topic" not "too localised".

Comment: @hammar Actually it does have to be reopened before it can be migrated. The only way mods can migrate is by using the Close function. But there's no reason the moderator can't do that themselves, so you'd be correct in saying normal users don't have to reopen the question in order for a mod to migrate it :)

Answer (score 5):

If you think that the question should be migrated even though it is closed then you can flag it for moderator review asking them to migrate it, similar to below:

[image]